# bootstrap center content in well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I'm trying to center some content with in a Well class using Twitter Bootstrap.

I've tried using row and various other CSS tricks.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container well well-main">
   <div id="marketing-mobile" class="title-marketing"><h3 class="text-center">Mobile</h3></div>
    <div class="widget-marketing span5">
        <div class="media">
          <a class="pull-left" href="#">
            <img class="media-object media-icons" img src="img/book.png">
          </a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h3 class="media-heading">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've taken a screenshot of the problem: [image]

Comment: Can you post your CSS as well?

Comment: Fixed it using offsetX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved, but if anyone is interested seeing an example, `offset3` in this case works to center the `span5`

```
<div class="container well well-main">
   <div id="marketing-mobile" class="title-marketing"><h3 class="text-center">Mobile</h3></div>
    <div class="widget-marketing span5 offset3">
        <div class="media">
          <a class="pull-left" href="#">
            <img class="media-object media-icons" src="//placehold.it/75x75">
          </a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h3 class="media-heading">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
</div></div>
```

http://bootply.com/65949